# WordPress dynamic menu with TinyMce

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

I came across a problem with TinyMce in Wordpress. I've got it set up in my theme, and it works just fine when it's hardcoded. I bump into a wall when trying to create a dynamic one.

In short, I need the content of a TinyMce instance (button > dropdown or array of checkbox instances) to be fetched from Custom Post Type pages or categories, whichever. Basically, I want the user to be able to add content from CPT or category in another page, choosing which CPT or which category they want from list.

I changed the javascript file to .js.php and added some php, which doesn't work when I try to execute a query in there.

I went through endless google search, and couldn't find anything useful. Any clue how to do this properly?

```
<!-- generate the menu in tinymce dynamically by pulling the case studies or case study categories -->
<!-- insert selected values as arguments to the shortcode -->
<!-- use the plugins > casestudy_pages to generate the content -->

<?php


$someValue = 'some value '; // this works when placed in the javascript below
//list terms in a given taxonomy (useful as a widget for twentyten)
$customPostTaxonomies = get_object_taxonomies('case_studies'); // creashes TinyMce

if(count($customPostTaxonomies) > 0)  
{
     foreach($customPostTaxonomies as $tax)
 {
     $args = array(
          'orderby' => 'name',
          'show_count' => 0,
          'pad_counts' => 0,
          'hierarchical' => 1,
          'taxonomy' => $tax,
          'title_li' => ''
        );
     $someValue = wp_list_categories( $args ); // creashes TinyMce
 }
}
?>


(function() {
tinymce.PluginManager.add('my_mce_button', function( editor, url ) {
    editor.addButton( 'my_mce_button', {
        text: 'Intelligent Office Shortcodes',
        icon: false,
        type: 'menubutton',
        menu: [
            {
                text: 'Add Children Pages Menu',
                        onclick: function() {

                            editor.insertContent( '[ChildrenMenu]');

                        }
            },
            {
                text: 'Add Children Pages Menu',
                        onclick: function() {

                            editor.insertContent( '[<?php echo $someValue; ?>]');

                        }
            },
        ]
    });
});
})();
```

Comment: You might also ask over at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will do. I also figured I could use query which takes the category from a custom field. This is far from the proper solution though.

Comment: Or create query based on page name, then assign category to my custom post types that will correspond to page names. Like so, it only requires you to create new categories by hand that are named exactly as your pages. Not ideal, but should work.